# Getting users based on group, but users, user_groups and groups kept in separate tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm assuming I need to use JOIN, but I'm not totally getting it. Here's my situation. I'm using ion_auth. It stores users in 'users', groups in 'groups' and stores users' group in 'users_groups'.

So if I have a group 'sales' with an id of '2', any user associated with that group appears in 'users_groups' as:

```
id  user_id  group_id
1   1        2
1   2        2
```

So how can I quickly return the results of a query like: get users from group 2. Would the JOIN command be what I'm looking for? I'm using CodeIgniter's Active Record but am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very basic join between two tables

```
SELECT users.* FROM users JOIN users_groups ON (users.id=users_groups.user_id) WHERE users_groups.group_id = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT list_of_fields FROM users JOIN users_group USING (group_id) WHERE users.group_id = 2
```

Assuming you used group_id as the field name on both tables

Comment: This won't work, `users_group` is a link table between `users` and `groups`, and as such `users` does not contain a `group_id` column